# Dividing a variable with two values and still return two values

Tags: python, python-3.4

In this code, I'm trying to divide variable `self.damage` by 20:

```
self.damage = map(lambda x: x/20, self.damage)
...
...
print("\nPICKAPOO's DAMAGE RATING WAS DECREASED BY 20%")
print("PICKAPOO's DAMAGE RATING IS NOW {}".format(str(self.damage)))
...
return self.damage
```

When I run it, I get this weird bug:

```
PICKAPOO's DAMAGE RATING WAS DECREASED BY 20%
PICKAPOO's DAMAGE RATING IS NOW <map object at 0x0000000002CB1128>
```

If I try any other code than the one I've got, it returns the same `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)` error.

Any thoughts, opinions, and advice for the future would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @200OK self.damage must be an iterable otherwise it would return an error, not a map object.

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, I just realized.

Comment: Doesn't work.
I get this: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /=: 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: @BenDover can you show us what `self.damage` is?

Comment: `[x / 20 for x in self.damage]` gives a list. It's also more readable than `map` with a `lambda`.

Comment: @BenDover What is the value for `self.damage` - it seems unusual it's a tuple.

Comment: `(65, 90)` Later in the code, it's used by `random.randrange(*self_damage)`

Comment: @BenDover I see, in that case, it makes sense, the best answer here would be to use a list comp as larsmans recommends.

Comment: @BenDover Your suggested edit on my post got rejected - it's worth noting that `list()` with a generator expression does the same thing as a list comprehension (but is less readable and efficient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `map()` returns an iterable, not a list. If you want a list, use `list(map(...))`.

The normal use case is just to iterate over it, which you can do just as you would if it was a list.

Arguably a better solution here is a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
[x / 20 for x in self.damage]
```

As a note, dividing by 20 is not a 20% reduction (it's a 95% reduction) - to do that, you want:

```
[x * 0.8 for x in self.damage]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `map` for this. `map` applies a function to every element in a list, while you're just trying to do simple division. Just use

```
self.damage = self.damage / 20
```

However, based on your text you are trying to reduce it by 20%, which is a different formula altogether:

```
self.damage = self.damage * (1 - 20 / 100)
```

**EDIT**:

It helps to know that `self.damage` is a tuple representing the damage range. Here's a function that can reduce that by `x`%:

```
self.damage = tuple(damageValue * (1 - x/100) for damageValue in self.damage)
```

If you don't care about keeping it as a tuple, you can use a list comprehension:

```
self.damage = [damageValue * (1 - x/100) for damageValue in self.damage]
```

Lists and tuples are very similar to work with, so it probably does not matter which one you use.

Comment: `self.damage` must be an iterable otherwise it would return an error, not a map object.